# PresentModalViewController in Storyboard programmatically iOS 5

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using storyboards for FIRST time in my iOS app. I have 2 views in my Storyboard (A & B). Lets say A is my initial view controller in my storyboard. When my app launched, I can see view controller A. So far everything is working as per expectation. Now in my view controller A, I am checking whether user is logged in or not. If user is not logged in then I want to present view controller B. How can I show B modally using PresentModalViewController programmatically?

Here is my set up

[image]

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
        NSLog(@"USER NOT LOGGED IN....");
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        LoginViewController *vc = (LoginViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

What you have done so far seems correct.. Did you remember to actually set the identifier of B in the storyboard?

Also, you might want to try

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
```

instead of what you're doing.

**Update:**

Here's what the `viewDidLoad` method might look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {

        NSLog(@"User is not logged in.");

        LoginViewController *vc = (LoginViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Also, I see from the image that your first view controller isn't set to any particular class. It just says "View Controller", while the second one shows "Login View Controller" correctly.

Note: I don't have access to Xcode right now, so I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Identifier is set storyboard correctly. Where should I write above line & what should I remove from my code ?

Comment: @iOSAppDev: Ok. Try the code I posted now. If that does not work there is something else that is wrong/missing. Also, make sure that those lines of code actually are executed. You could also add an `NSLog` statement in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller you want to show (LoginViewController), just to make sure it is loaded.